# compiled libraries vs header only libraries

Tags: c++

I am newish to C++ and I am trying to understand why some libraries need to be compiled first.

For example some boost libraries are header only (e.g. msm) some others need to be compiled (e.g timer)

I can't find a nice explanation for why is this so. Can someone help me understand?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain kinds of things are kept in headers only rather than having the usual `.h(pp)` and `.cpp` files. Only one I know are templated classes and functions. Which I'm sure boost takes advantage of.

Comment: So why can't I add the .cpp and .h files in my code (exactly like I include boost/msm.hpp in my code) and compile?

Comment: @Kam No one said you can't.

Comment: @Kam: Not exactly, you cannot `#include` those _cpp_ files and expect them to work. You can add them to your project, though, and compile them as part of it.

Comment: Yeah that's right but you can add the .cpp and .h files into your project and compile them yourself. Just don't do `#include "file.cpp"`

Comment: Thank you now I get it! I thought when they mention that a lib needs building I thought adding its .cc files to my makefile will not work! now I know the difference. Thanks!

Comment: @Kam: Adding their _.cc files_ to your makefile **will** work, what **won't** work is `#include`-ing them...

Answer (score 1):

- Header only libraries are easier to use but harder to write. You just need to `#include` them.
- They have more optimization opportunities, but they take longer to compile. There is more code and more context to optimize, but that takes its time.
- And last but not least, `template`s must be defined in header files.

But there is a limit to how much one can get away with, or how much one is willing to endure, by using header files. For instance, dealing with static objects in *shared libraries*, which by the way the **C++** standard knows nothing about, sometimes just cannot be done in headers.